# Trouble with simple script :(

Tags: bash, scripts, dd, .sh

Could someone please tell me why this script doesn't run correctly. Seems to be a problem with the if statement as i keep getting the error:

```
/home/sinttx/Development/backup/ddbackup.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
/home/sinttx/Development/backup/ddbackup.sh: line 18:  if [ "$exit" -eq 0 ] ; then'
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#(SINTTX) Function and if statement to backup/clone /dev/???.

 echo "
 THIS WILL COMPLETE A BACKUP OF DESIRED /DEV "

 echo -n "Enter desired name for saved file (File will be saved with extention .iso) and press [ENTER]: "
 read iso  
 echo -n "Enter the device to be duplicated/backed up (Eg /dev/sda) and press [ENTER]: "  
 read dev  
 echo -n "Enter the desired path/location for the backup file (Eg /home/USERNAME/backups/) and press [ENTER]: "  
 read path  
 echo "PLEASE ENTER THE SUDO PASSWORD (IF PROMPTED) AND WAIT :-)  
 NOTE: THIS COULD TAKE SOME TIME DEPENDING ON FILE SIZE AND HARDWARE SPEED!!"  
 sudo dd if="$dev" of="$path"/"$iso"  
 exit=$?  
 if [ "$exit" -eq 0 ] ; then  
  echo "SUCCESS"  
 else  
  echo "BACKUP HAS SUFFERED AN ERROR AND DID NOT COMPLETE SUCCESSFULLY"  
fi
```

Comment: @sinttx: Have you modified the script on a MS Windows system?

Comment: hi @Jan thanks i tried your advice but still the same problem :(

Comment: @Cyrus Nope I am using Kubuntu only

Comment: @sinttx: feel free to check your file for non printable characters: `cat -v ddbackup.sh`.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus i wasn't aware of that command but there doesn't seem to be an issue to my eyes.

Comment: **THANKS @Cyrus** I was incorrect there was one non printable character! I will need to remember this command. Thanks again works a treat :)

Comment: @terdon Removed my wrong comment, thank you for making me aware of it!

Answer (score 1):

As [@Cyrus suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534779/trouble-with-simple-script#comment731186_534779), you probably have a non-printing character there that is causing you problems. The most likely reason is that at some point you edited this script from a Windows machine and a `\r` was added to the end of the line. You can check if anything is there on that line by running

```
grep 'if [ "$exit"' script.sh | od -c
```

That will show all characters, including non-printing ones.

If you do indeed have a `\r` there, you can fix it by running"

```
sed -i 's/\r//' script.sh
```

Or, installing `dos2unix` (`sudo apt-get install dos2unix`) and running

```
dos2unix script.sh > fixed.sh
```